# Bounded functional on X

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a set of sequences $(x_n)_{n\geq 1}$ for which exists $M\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{k=1}^n |x_k|\leq M$, for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$. $X$ is Banach space, if $\|x\|=\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{k=1}^n |x_k|$, but how to prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x_n}{3^n}$ is bounded functional on $X$? I only got that $l(x)\leq \|x\|sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}2^n$, which is not bounded?
Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: look up "summation by parts"

Comment: Hey @alans. Sorry for writing here, but you deleted your last question just in that moment, when I realized how to use polar coordinates for double integration. If you are interesting, then I can write it. If no, then, again sorry and shortly after your answer I'll delete this comment.

Comment: @zkutch I am interested in your answer, I will undelete question.

Comment: Ok, @alans. Write me, please, where I can find it.

Comment: @zkutch Check my last question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am restating:
$$X=\{(x_n)\in\mathbb{C}^\mathbb{N}|\sup_{n\geq1}\bigg(\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{j=1}^n|x_j|\bigg)<\infty\} $$
and the norm is given by $\|(x_n)\|=\sup_{n\geq1}\bigg(\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{j=1}^n|x_j|\bigg)$. Apparently $X$ is a Banach space endowed with this norm, as OP states. We have the functional $l:X\to\mathbb{C}$ given by $l(x_n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x_n}{3^n}$ and we want to show that this is bounded.

Answer: let $N\geq1$. Then **warning: many computations ahead.**
$$\bigg|\sum_{j=1}^N\frac{x_j}{3^j}\bigg|\leq\sum_{j=1}^N\frac{|x_j|}{3^j}=\frac{1}{3^N}\bigg(|x_N|+3|x_{N-1}|+3^2|x_{N-2}|+\dots+3^{N-2}|x_2|+3^{N-1}|x_1|\bigg)=$$

$$=\frac{1}{3^N}\bigg(\sum_{j=1}^N|x_j|+(3-1)|x_{N-1}|+(3^2-1)|x_{N-2}|+\dots+(3^{N-2}-1)|x_{2}|+(3^{N-1}-1)|x_1|\bigg) $$

$$=\frac{1}{3^N}\bigg(\sum_{j=1}^N|x_j|+(3^1-1)\sum_{j=1}^{N-1}|x_j|+((3^2-1)-(3^1-1))|x_{N-2}|+\dots+((3^{N-2}-1)-(3^1-1))|x_2|+((3^{N-1}-1)-(3-1))|x_1|\bigg)=$$
$$\frac{1}{3^N}\bigg(\sum_{j=1}^N|x_j|+(3^1-1)\sum_{j=1}^{N-1}|x_j|+(3^2-3^1)|x_{N-2}|+\dots+(3^{N-2}-3^1)|x_2|+(3^{N-1}-3^1)|x_1|\bigg)=\dots$$

$$\dots=\frac{1}{3^N}\bigg(\sum_{j=1}^N|x_j|+(3^1-1)\sum_{j=1}^{N-1}|x_j|+(3^2-3^1)\sum_{j=1}^{N-2}|x_j|+(3^3-3^2)\sum_{j=1}^{N-3}|x_j|+\dots$$ $$+(3^{N-2}-3^{N-1})\sum_{j=1}^{2}|x_j|+(3^{N-1}-3^{N-2})|x_1|\bigg)\leq$$
$$\leq\frac{\|x\|}{3^N}\bigg(2^N+(3^1-1)2^{N-1}+(3^2-3^1)2^{N-2}+(3^3-3^2)2^{N-3}+\dots+(3^{N-2}-3^{N-1})2^2+(3^{N-1}-3^{N-2})2^1\bigg)=$$
$$=\frac{\|x\|}{3^N}\bigg((2^N+3^12^{N-1}+3^22^{N-2}+\dots+3^{N-1}2^1)-(2^{N-1}+3^12^{(N-1)-1}+3^22^{(N-1)-2)}+\dots+3^{(N-1)-2}2^2+3^{(N-1)-1}2^1)\bigg)=$$
$$=\frac{\|x\|}{3^N}\bigg((2^N+3^12^{N-1}+3^22^{N-2}+\dots+3^{N-1}2^1+3^N)-(2^{N-1}+3^12^{(N-1)-1}+3^22^{(N-1)-2)}+\dots+3^{(N-1)-2}2^2+3^{(N-1)-1}2^1+3^{N-1})-3^N+3^{N-1}\bigg)=$$
$$=\frac{\|x\|}{3^N}\bigg((3^{N+1}-2^{N+1})-(3^N-2^N)-3^N+3^{N-1}\bigg)$$

where we used the identity $x^{n+1}-y^{n+1}=(x-y)(x^{n}+x^{n-1}y+x^{n-2}y^2+\dots+xy^{n-1}+y^n)$. Let $N\to\infty$ and this yields
$$|l(x)|\leq\frac{4}{3}\|x\| $$
so $l$ is bounded.

Comment: Trust me, the computations work out!